# Що таке "жижки"?

Tags: значення-слів, фразеологізми

Мабуть багато людей чули такий фразеологізм "*жижки трусяться*". [Фразеологічний словник української мови](http://svitslova.com/idioms-dictionary/2022-azh-zhyzhky-triasutsia.html) цілком пояснює його значення. А як щодо слово *"жижки"*? Що воно означає?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Визначення із словника української мови online (1-8 томи)

> **[ЖИЖКИ](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=27041&page=908)**  жи́жо́к, мн., розм. Задній бік колін, підколінні сухожилки. *Сказав Явтух Рябку: – Оце тебе за те По жижках .. так
>   гарно пошмагали, Що Пан із Панею сю цілу ніч не спали* (П.
>   Гулак-Артемовський)

Comment: обожемій українська має слово для заднього боку колін. МАРВЕЛОС. ІНКРЕДІБЛ.
пане @bytebuster, можете видаляти коментар, як побачите, просто я мав висловитися.